# Setting up multiple signers in hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

My deploy script.

```js
const hre = require("hardhat")
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
const fs = require("fs")


const tokens = (n) => {
  return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), 'ether')
}


async function main() {

// setup the accounts
  const [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners()

  // deploy RealEstate
  const RealEstate = await ethers.getContractFactory('RealEstate')
  const realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy()
  await realEstate.deployed()

  console.log(`Deployed Real Estate Contract at: ${realEstate.address}`)
  console.log(`Minting properties...\n`)

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).mint(`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQVcpsjrA6cr1iJjZAodYwmPekYgbnXGo4DFubJiLc2EB/${i + 1}.json`)
    await transaction.wait()
  }

  // deploy Escrow
  const Escrow = await ethers.getContractFactory('Escrow')
  const escrow = await Escrow.deploy(
    realEstate.address,
    seller.address,
    inspector.address,
    lender.address
  )
  await escrow.deployed()

  console.log(`Deployed Escrow Contract at: ${escrow.address}`)
  console.log(`Listing properties...\n`)

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    // approve properties...
    let transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).approve(escrow.address, i + 1)
    await transaction.wait()
  }

  // listing properties...
  transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).list(1, buyer.address, tokens(20), tokens(10))
  await transaction.wait()

  transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).list(2, buyer.address, tokens(15), tokens(5))
  await transaction.wait()

  transaction = await escrow.connect(seller).list(3, buyer.address, tokens(10), tokens(5))
  await transaction.wait()

  console.log(`Finished.`)

}


// recommended this pattern to be able to use async/await everywhere and properly handle errors.
main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
  process.exitCode = 1
})
```

My hardhat.config

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("solidity-coverage")
require("hardhat-gas-reporter")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers")
require("dotenv").config()


const MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.MAINNET_RPC_URL || "your_mainnet_api_key"
const GOERLI_RPC_URL = process.env.GOERLI_RPC_URL || "your_infura_api_key"
const POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL = process.env.POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL || "your-api-key"
const MUMBAI_RPC_URL = process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL || "your-api-key"
const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY || "your_private_key"
const ETHERSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY || "your_etherscan_api_key"
const POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY = process.env.POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY || "Your polygonscan API key"
const REPORT_GAS = false


    module.exports = {
      defaultNetwork: "hardhat",
      networks: {
          hardhat: {
              chainId: 31337,
          },

          localhost: {
              chainId: 31337,
          },

          goerli: {
              url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
              accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
              //   accounts: {
              //     mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
              //   },
              saveDeployments: true,
              chainId: 5,
          },

          mainnet: {
              url: MAINNET_RPC_URL,
              accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
              //   accounts: {
              //     mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
              //   },
              saveDeployments: true,
              chainId: 1,
          },

          polygon: {
              url: POLYGON_MAINNET_RPC_URL,
              accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
              saveDeployments: true,
              chainId: 137,
          },

          mumbai: {
            url: MUMBAI_RPC_URL,
            accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
            saveDeployments: true,
            chainId: 137,
        },

      },


      etherscan: {
          // yarn hardhat verify --network <NETWORK> <CONTRACT_ADDRESS> <CONSTRUCTOR_PARAMETERS>
          apiKey: {
              goerli: ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
              polygon: POLYGONSCAN_API_KEY,
          },

          customChains: [
              {
                  network: "goerli",
                  chainId: 5,
                  urls: {
                      apiURL: "https://api-goerli.etherscan.io/G9MDR45ASFJ1IR2PEUXJJV17YHXQ2MNHF6",
                      browserURL: "https://goerli.etherscan.io",
                  },
              },
          ],
      },


      gasReporter: {
          enabled: REPORT_GAS,
          currency: "USD",
          outputFile: "gas-report.txt",
          noColors: true,
          // coinmarketcap: process.env.COINMARKETCAP_API_KEY,
      },


      contractSizer: {
          runOnCompile: false,
          only: ["Escrow"],
      },


      solidity: {
        version: "0.8.17",
        settings: {
          optimizer: {
            enabled: true,
            runs: 200
          }
        }
      },


      mocha: {
          timeout: 500000, // 500 seconds max for running tests
      },
}
```

I am finding it difficult to deploy the project on Goerli. It is working fine on localhost.

The error is:

```js
  Escrow
    Deployment
      1) "before each" hook for "Returns NFT address"


  0 passing (4s)
  1 failing

  1) Escrow
       "before each" hook for "Returns NFT address":
     Error: sending a transaction requires a signer (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=contracts/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
      at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:420:20)
      at step (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:29:53)
      at C:\Users\VidhanMangla\Desktop\mqube-mbrick-v2\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71
      at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at __awaiter (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
      at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:421:16)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\unit\Escrow.js:24:60)
```

Comment: can you add the error stack trace?

Comment: Added the error message.

Comment: I met this kind of error when I passed an ```account.address``` instead of just an ```account```. Your stacktrace doesn't help much as there is no clear mapping between each line in stacktrace and your code, quick overview doesn't give a clue either. I would suggest to isolate step by step your code and run deployment on the ```testnet``` to localise the issue.

Comment: Also double check your contract deployment -- the ```.deployed()``` call looks redundant. Here is how I did the similar scenario https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/test/SwapChainV2.ts

Comment: @VidhanMangla the error stack is not aligning with the script code you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

```json
        goerli: {
              url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
              accounts: PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [PRIVATE_KEY] : [], // <--- HERE
              saveDeployments: true,
              chainId: 5,
            }
```

referring to the accounts section, Here you have defined only one account, hence you can get one signer when you execute the following line.

```typescript
    const [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners()
    // buyer won't be undefined but all others will be undefined
```

As the solution I would suggest something like this.

```json
        goerli: {
             url: GOERLI_RPC_URL,
              accounts: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined && process.env.PRIVATE_KEY1 != undefined &&  process.env.PRIVATE_KEY2 != undefined && process.env.PRIVATE_KEY3 != undefined ?
          [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,process.env.PRIVATE_KEY1,process.env.PRIVATE_KEY2,process.env.PRIVATE_KEY3] : [],
              saveDeployments: true,
              chainId: 5,
            }
```

and setup the necessary variables in `.env` file

```typescript
// setup the accounts
  const [buyer, seller, inspector, lender] = await ethers.getSigners()
 //<---------- Here the seller, inspector and lender would be undefined -->

  
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 // ---- hence an error occurs here
    const transaction = await realEstate.connect(seller).mint(`https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQVcpsjrA6cr1iJjZAodYwmPekYgbnXGo4DFubJiLc2EB/${i + 1}.json`)
    await transaction.wait()
  }
```

similarly the `.connect(seller)` `.connect(inspector)` `.connect(lender)` will have similar errors.